# How do I change Office paste options from C# WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, ms-office

I'm building a program to change and control Windows and Office settings from a central interface (that's easier to find and use than Microsoft stuff), but I'm hitting a snag in changing Office settings. I've found documentation for them:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.options.pasteformatfromexternalsource

In this one, it lists the following:

```cs
public Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdPasteOptions PasteFormatFromExternalSource { get; set; }
```

But how do I use that? I can't use it as a variable or method. I can't find any code samples that show how to use this. I've already installed microsoft.office.interop.word through Nuget.

Comment: you want to change word paste behaviour, without starting word? or want change the behaviour while word is openning?

Comment: I want to change office settings from C#. It has nothing to do with Word or any Word files.

Comment: i'm just take word as example. aren't you doing the same thing?

Comment: Ok, I understand. Yes, I want to change the settings without starting word. Ideally, the settings are stored in the registry or a file somewhere that I can manipulate whether or not any office software is active.

Comment: i don't think common settings in office are in registry. WdPasteOptions for example, should be a runtime config, not persistent.

Comment: Bummer. So this might not be something that can be done.